# How to find files in website directory?

Tags: php, web-crawler

I'm creating a web crawler. I'm ganna give it an URL and it will scan through the directory and sub directories for .html files. I've been looking at two alternatives:

1. `scandir($url)`. This works on local files but not on http sites. Is this because of file permissions? I'm guessing it shouldn't work since it would be dangerous for everyone to have access to your website files.
2. Searching for links and following them. I can do file_get_contents on the index file, find links and then follow them to their .html files.

Do any of these 2 work or is there a third alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to look for html files is to parse throuhg the file content returned by the server, unless by small chance they have enabled directory browsing on the server, which is one of the first things disabled usually, you dont have access to browse directory listings, only the content they are prepared to show you, and let you use.

You would have to start a http://www.mysite.com and work onwards scanning for links to html files, what if they have asp/php or other files which then return html content?

Comment: That's what i thought. I forgot to say but I will of course search for asp, php etc as well. Although, I came across a problem when using file_get_contents for .php. It does not get the content echoed by php.

Comment: I havent seen that unless it was phps, or, specifically designed for the php script to do so.

Comment: What exactly does get_file_contents do? Does it return the source code or the actual code?

Comment: Can you imagine if it let you at the underneath asp/php source code? It would let so many hackers hack everything! no, it just returns the returned data - wether thats html, exe, img.. depends on what you called, if you call it on a jpg, you'd get jpg data

Comment: This is strange.. When I do file_get_contents on local files the plain php code is return as well. But when I do it on online websites it returns only the generated html.

Comment: For local files I can understand a little better, but for remote ones it cant return source.. for local ones, as long as you access it via the http://server/code.php then Id expect the generated output, not the source too

Answer (score 1):

Have you considering using `wget`? It can crawl a website and download only files with a particular extension.